# Getting the highest correlation coefficient from the given data set

Tags: matlab, for-loop, correlation

I would like to compare the following given data set

```
a = '235 148 89 19 222';
b = '112 128 144 160 176';
c = '192 192 192 192 192';
d = '64 64 64 64 64';
```

with

```
y = [230 138 79 15 212];
```

Then calculate the correlation coefficient by comparing each of the given data set with `y`. Then, display the string with the highest correlation coefficient found.
I can find it for calculating it for two values with the command

```
c = corrcoef( a, y );   
c = abs(c(2,1));
```

but how do I iterate through each data set using a for loop and display the result with highest the `corrcoef`?

Here is the piece of code which I have written, but I don't know how to proceed with the 'for loop'

```
a = '235 148 89 19 222';
b = '112 128 144 160 176';
c = '192 192 192 192 192';
d = '64 64 64 64 64';

y = '230 138 79 15 212';

s = {a;b;c;d};
s = cellfun(@strsplit, s, 'UniformOutput', false);
s = vertcat(s{:});

for i = 1:size(s,1)

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all the easy way to transform a string of number to array is using
str2num like this:

```
>> an = str2num(a)

an =

   235   148    89    19   222
```

to concatenate stings in a matrix as rows use char and then convert it to a matrix:

```
>> S = char(a,b,c,d)

S =

235 148 89 19 222  
112 128 144 160 176
192 192 192 192 192
64 64 64 64 64     

>> N = str2num(S)

N =

   235   148    89    19   222
   112   128   144   160   176
   192   192   192   192   192
    64    64    64    64    64
```

then the only thing you need is to go trought the matrix:

```
>> [rows,columns] = size(N)

rows =

     4


columns =

     5
```

we need to iterate over all the rows

```
>> N(1,:)

ans =

   235   148    89    19   222
```

in the matlab help:

```
R = corrcoef(A,B) returns coefficients between two random variables A and B.

>> R = corrcoef(N(1,:),y)

R =

    1.0000    0.9995
    0.9995    1.0000
```

so then applying your measure to the loop

```
>> for i = 1:rows
R = corrcoef(N(i,:),y);
rr(i) = abs(R(2,1));
end
>> rr

rr =

    0.9995    0.2789       NaN       NaN
```

finally the max of that vector is the row that you want

```
>> [value,position] = max(rr)

value =

    0.9995


position =

     1

>> N

N =

   235   148    89    19   222
   112   128   144   160   176
   192   192   192   192   192
    64    64    64    64    64

>> N(position,:)

ans =

   235   148    89    19   222
```

Comment: How can I display the result in an array; say `y = [63 63 63 63 63]` so the closest output should be `d = [64 64 64 64 64]`. So how can I display that result (entire matching vector)?

Comment: I added the final solution, it was only to find the max value, please if this answer heps you upvopte and check as valid

Answer (score 0):

Is there a special reason for using strings and cells instead of integer values and matrices?

What about the following solution:

```
a = [235 148 89 19 222;...
    112 128 144 160 176;...
    192 192 192 192 192;...
    64 64 64 64 64];

b = zeros(size(a));

y = [230 138 79 15 212];

for i=1:length(a(:,1))
    b(i,:) = a(i,:)- y;
end;

[~, minLine] = min(sum(abs(b')));

disp(minLine);
```

Here every line in the given dataset `a`(matrix) is compared with the given vector `y`, by calculating the difference and storing the values in a second matrix `b`.
After the loop the minimal sum is calculated and gives you the line in `a`, which is correlating most to `y`

Comment: Thank you! It almost works, I mean it detects that the closest value to y is line 1 and it displays it correctly but can it give the result [235 148 89 19 222] instead of displaying just 1.

Comment: And could you please do it by using corrcoef?